# O que fazer quando uma pergunta não teve respostas nem comentários para orientação, mesmo sendo oferecido recompensa?

Tags: debate, recompensa

O que fazer quando uma pergunta não teve respostas nem comentários para orientação, mesmo sendo oferecido recompensa?

As vezes o que mais preciso é uma luz de onde e como me orientar para resolver algum problema, porem as perguntas só tem visitas e nem um comentário para ajudar.

O que fazer, pois já recebi medalhas tipo esqueceram de mim etc, e nem sei o que isso quer dizer.

Ex:

[Usar o getServiceLocator() no layout, helper, plugins - no ZF2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63163/usar-o-getservicelocator-no-layout-helper-plugins-no-zf2) <sup>(deletada, somente para usuários 10k)</sup>

[Router no Zend 1.12 ocultar controller e action](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60360/router-no-zend-1-12-ocultar-controller-e-action)

[Redirecionamento de páginas 404 para pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58946/redirecionamento-de-p%C3%A1ginas-404-para-pesquisa)

Comment: Estamos com falta de especialistas?

Answer (score 9):

> Desculpe Rafael, mas não notei nenhuma recompensa oferecida em nenhuma das perguntas.

- [Router no Zend 1.12 ocultar controller e action](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60360/router-no-zend-1-12-ocultar-controller-e-action)

  Eu pessoalmente acho que muitos são capazes de responder, mas no momento que você fez referencia ao Zend, tornou mais difícil de responder, pois é bem comum ver o uso de `.htaccess`, mas nem todos usam Zend e isto causa um certo receio para algum usuário lhe responder, pois ele fica sem certeza se irá causar algum problema ao framework uma resposta somente baseada em `.htaccess`. Outra coisa além do `.htaccess` é necessário quem irá responder entender o sistema de rotas do Zend.
- [Redirecionamento de páginas 404 para pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58946/redirecionamento-de-p%C3%A1ginas-404-para-pesquisa)

  É a mesma situação da *Router no Zend 1.12 ocultar controller e action*, porém há dois detalhes, o primeiro é que houve uma resposta e tentativa de ajuda pela parte do @Otto e outro que a situação não tem haver com `.htaccess` e exige algum conhecimento técnico da estrutura do Magento, como somos uma comunidade mais de programadores é um pouco difícil encontrar pessoas *especialistas em um CMS* (acho que é isto que o Magento é, corrija-me se eu estiver enganado).
- [Usar o getServiceLocator() no layout, helper, plugins - no ZF2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63163/usar-o-getservicelocator-no-layout-helper-plugins-no-zf2)

  Esta realmente eu nem sei por onde começar, o que posso lhe dizer para reforçar isto é que o *Zend* é popular, mas é mais fácil encontrar desenvolvedores que usam Laravel, CodeIgniter e CakePHP. Porém isto é apenas a minha opinião, posso estar enganado, a ideia que eu quero passar é: É difícil encontrar desenvolvedores que usem Zend e mais difícil encontrar desenvolvedores Zend que tenham conhecimento avançado dele.

Nota: Outro ponto que vale ressaltar é a versão usada do Zend, como dito pelo @gmsantos:

> Algo que dificulta também é a versão utilizada. Embora ela ainda receba atualizações de segurança, já temos a o ZF 2 e o ZF3 está em pleno desenvolvimento. Pretendo começar a estudar um pouco de Zend Framework, mas provavelmente não vou precisar da versão 1.

Comment: Algo que dificulta também é a versão utilizada. Embora ela ainda receba atualizações de segurança, já temos a o ZF 2 e o ZF3 está em pleno desenvolvimento. Pretendo começar a estudar um pouco de Zend Framework, mas provavelmente não vou precisar da versão 1.

Comment: pelo que eu vi mudou algumas coisas. Na época do ZF1 (PHP 5.2) ainda não existiam namespaces (tanto que eles são "emulados" com underlines) ou PSR-0/4.

Comment: Me parece que atualizar do 1 para o 2 pode ser [bem](http://pt.slideshare.net/clarkphp/zend-con-practicalzf1zf2migration) [mais problemático](http://www.sasaprolic.com/2012/10/when-migration-to-zend-framework-2.html) do que parece @Guilherme.